Apach Ignite on GraalVM
Does Apache Ignite 3.0 support GraalVM? I am trying to find more details around the level of support? Does it apply to both thin/thick clients?
We have been unsuccessful in our previous attempt to get Ignite to work with GraalVM, version used was 2.13 with java 17.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a question for the product vendor to answer, and likely one they have answered on their own product site or documentation. It's not a programming question within the scope of the site. It also asks multiple questions, which is outside the scope of this site.
